# How to add a Location field in drupal 7

Tags: 7, location

I have my location module enabled but I cannot see a **location field** while creating a new form.How can I add location field to a content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed installing the location_cck sub module it provides location field type to add on any content type out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the [Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) module installed instead. You can then add location information e.g Longitude/Latitude.